# Выделение памяти под структуры

Tags: c, указатели, память, malloc

Всем привет.
У меня есть структура

```
typedef struct _Node {
struct _Node* parent;
struct _Node* left;
struct _Node* right;


unsigned short int mark;
struct _Node* child;
int degree;

unsigned int key;
type* value;
} Node;
```

Я выделяю память и определяю поля для экземпляра структуры

```
Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof (Node));
if (node == NULL) exit(1);

node->key = key; //Здесь ошибка
node->value = value;
node->degree = 0;
node->mark = FALSE;
node->parent = NULL;
node->child = NULL;
node->left = node;
node->right = node;
```

Но при попытке определить поле экземпляра получаю ошибку вида.

> Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи.
> node было 0xFFFFFFFFAD0955D0.

Как мне решить проблему? Заранее благодарю.

UPD:Меня просили добавить код целиком. Вот он ниже:

```
#include<math.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef int type; // Тип хранимых данных

typedef struct _Node {
    struct _Node* parent;
    struct _Node* left;
    struct _Node* right;


    unsigned short int mark;
    struct Node* child;
    int degree;

    unsigned int key;
    type* value; // Я решил использовать typedef, чтобы не хранить 
} Node;          // указатель на void

typedef struct _FibHeap {
    Node* min;
    unsigned int nnodes;
} FibHeap;
void FibHeapAddNodeToRootList(Node* node, Node* h);
FibHeap* FibHeapInsert(FibHeap* heap, unsigned int key, type* value);

int main()
{
    FibHeap* fh = (FibHeap*)malloc(sizeof(FibHeap));

    int val = 0;

    FibHeapInsert(fh, 10, &val);
    FibHeapInsert(fh, 16, &val);
    FibHeapInsert(fh, 18, &val);
    FibHeapInsert(fh, 6, &val);
    FibHeapInsert(fh, 9, &val);
    FibHeapInsert(fh, 26, &val);
    FibHeapInsert(fh, 12, &val);

    return 0;
}

void FibHeapAddNodeToRootList(Node* node, Node* h)
{
    if (h == NULL)  return;
    if (h->left == h) {
        h->left = node;
        h->right = node;
        node->right = h;
        node->left = h;
    }
    else {
        Node* lnode = h->left;
        h->left = node;
        node->right = h;
        node->left = lnode;
        lnode->right = node;
    }
}

FibHeap* FibHeapInsert(FibHeap* heap, unsigned int key, type* value)
{
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof (Node));
    if (node == NULL) exit(1);

    node->key = key;
    node->value = value;
    node->degree = 0;
    node->mark = FALSE;
    node->parent = NULL;
    node->child = NULL;
    node->left = node;
    node->right = node;

    Node* min = heap->min;
    FibHeapAddNodeToRootList(node, heap->min);
    if ((heap->min == NULL) || (node->key < heap->min->key))
        heap->min = node;
    heap->nnodes += 1;
    return heap;
}
```

Comment: между `Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof (Node));` и `node->key = key;` идёт порча памяти. Угадать тяжело. Код выложите поподробнее. *`struct Node* child;`,`type* value;` - что за типы?*

Comment: Проверил код, скомпилировал, запустил  - нет ошибок. Значит прав @AlexGlebe, между malloc() и node->key = key портится node

Comment: Тут намешано тайп и структ. Мне этот момент не нравится

Comment: @AlexGlebe, struct Node* child; - это просто struct _Node* child; здесь просто было опечатка. Про type* value; написано в коде. И я привел код полностью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну смотрите, что вы делаете:

```
FibHeap* fh = (FibHeap*)malloc(sizeof(FibHeap));
```

Т.е. `fh` указывает на неинициализированную память, и что там за значения `min` и `nnodes` — Дейкстра его знает...

Далее вы вызываете

```
FibHeapInsert(fh, 10, &val);
```

а в ней —

```
Node* min = heap->min;
FibHeapAddNodeToRootList(node, heap->min);
```

Т.е. передаете опять же неизвестно что под видом `heap->min` как `Node* h`...

```
FibHeapAddNodeToRootList(Node* node, Node* h)
{
    if (h == NULL)  return;   
    if (h->left == h) {
```

И куда вы обращаетесь как к `h->left`? Вот и получаете неприятности...

По крайней мере при попытке воспроизведения вашей программы я получил их именно в этой строке, а не там, куда показываете вы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Моя проблема, о которой шла речь выше, возникала из-за неправильной настройки VS, я только сейчас смог разобраться в сути проблемы. А по поводу вашего замечания, я напишу функцию для корректного выделения памяти под FibHeap и определения полей структуры. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: А нельзя подробнее — какая неправильная настройка приводит к такому результату? Может ведь и другим пригодиться...

Comment: Если настраивать согласно этому видео, то все будет работать отлично.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkGcnGNo22g&ab_channel=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8286

Comment: Мне не надо, как будет работать, а хочется понять, что в настройках могло не дать нормально работать. Я такую настройку не представляю...

Comment: Мне трудно сказать в чем была проблема. Единственное, что я могу сделать, это отправить вам проект.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gtwOMTp5rYEzoYJTSo4KRfDzuPUjMrrl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *Этот файл нельзя открыть, так как он нарушает Условия использования.*

Comment: Извините, за потраченное время. Вот точно рабочая ссылка https://mega.nz/file/nZ9DgbiL#uRK-DSqWAHcEzT1Kvp_FgM3-i6riiqzwLHat8UM_EqA

Comment: Блин! У вас тривиальнейшая ошибка. Вы не включили необходимый заголовочный файл, без этого C считает, что функция возвращает `int` (32 бита), в то время как вы работаете в 64-разрядном режиме. Возвращенный указатель режется, и вы получаете фиг знает что вместо нормального указателя! Наверняка "исправленной настройкой" стал переход от x64 к x86... Всего-то...